# Get current date and time in javascript of format: 2015-03-01 03:09:03

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, date

I want to get current date and time in javascript like this: **2015-03-01 03:09:03**

How can I achieve such format? (**Show zero before a number when less than 9**)

Actually I am comparing date and time with mysql date and time in NODE.JS with mysql plugin. So my javascript date and time format must be the same as mysql default date and time format i.e : **2015-03-01 03:09:03**

Currently I am using:

```
 var currentdate     = new Date(); 
 var datetime        = currentdate.getFullYear() + "-" +
                       (currentdate.getMonth()+1)  + "-"+
                       currentdate.getDate() + " "  + 
                       currentdate.getHours() + ":"   +
                       currentdate.getMinutes() + ":" + 
                       currentdate.getSeconds();
```

**Mysql Query in NODE.JS:**

```
var paramUpdate = {}
stateObject.connection.query("UPDATE timersDb SET notificationFlag = '1' 
                              WHERE requestTime < '"+datetime+"' AND
                              notificationFlag = '0'", 
                              paramUpdate , function(err, rows){
                                            if(err){
                                                throw err;
                                            } 
                                            else{ } 
                                        });
```

But this code is generating date and time like this: **2015-3-1 3:9:3**
which is not valid according to mysql date and time standards.

Can anyone guide me what is the best possible solution to achieve current date and time in javascript like this: **2015-03-01 03:09:03**

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a function which will add a leading 0 if the value is less than 10. Try this:

```
var currentdate     = new Date(); 
var datetime        = addZero(currentdate.getFullYear()) + "-" +
                      addZero(currentdate.getMonth()+1)  + "-"+
                      addZero(currentdate.getDate()) + " "  + 
                      addZero(currentdate.getHours()) + ":"   +
                      addZero(currentdate.getMinutes()) + ":" + 
                      addZero(currentdate.getSeconds());

function addZero(str)
{
    return str < 10 ? ('0' + str) : str;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

all you need to is to append zeros if its less than 10.

```
 var currentdate = new Date();
var appendZero = function (value) {
    if (parseint(value) > 9) {
        return value;
    } else {
        return "0" + value.toString();
    }
}
var datetime = currentdate.getFullYear() + "-" +
    appendZero(currentdate.getMonth() + 1) + "-" +
    appendZero(currentdate.getDate()) + " " +
    appendZero(currentdate.getHours()) + ":" +
    appendZero(currentdate.getMinutes()) + ":" +
    appendZerocurrentdate.getSeconds());
```

Comment: hmmm actually there is one more thing. there are a difference of few ours in mysql date and javascript date. Why is that so ?

Comment: that's because of Timezone issue.. your server and client will be in different timezones.. new Date() gives date with local timezone

Answer (score 0):

You could be using [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/)

```
moment(currentDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss');
```

The better solution is to use a query builder such as [knexjs](http://knexjs.org/) that will automatically serialize you data into a SQL query so you won't need to worry about all the quirks and details (and will also protect you against SQL injections)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 var currentdate     = new Date(); 
 var datetime        = currentdate.getFullYear() + "-" +
                       ('0' + (currentdate.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2)  + "-"+
                       ('0' + currentdate.getDate()).slice(-2) + " "  + 
                       ('0' + currentdate.getHours()).slice(-2) + ":"   +
                       ('0' + currentdate.getMinutes()).slice(-2) + ":" + 
                       ('0' + currentdate.getSeconds()).slice(-2);

> datetime
#"2015-05-31 22:15:59"
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using [`toISOString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString)? Browser compatibility table shows a wide support.

So you expression will be a one liner:

```
new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 19).replace('T', ' ');
```

The generated output:

> "2017-06-29 17:45:52"